# sorting without sort

Tags: python, sorting, loops

Basically, I want to sort numbers without using 'sort'.
what I plan to do is create a new list and put every Min number into it 
such as:

```
for item in List:
    if item < (Min):
        Min = item
        nList.append(Min)
        List.remove(Min)
```

which List is input list, Min=List[0] and nList =[]

How can I use double loop to keep it run?

Comment: ummm... you reached the end of the list?

Comment: you have no logic if item > Min

Comment: there is no other problems with indenting :) sry guys I just typed run.my function wants to find the minimum number and append it into new list and removed from original one. so in the end, will return a new sorted list. but the loop stop after it found the min one. so question is how to keep it running?

Comment: @user1813564 make a second loop

Comment: As a side note, it is almost always a bad idea to do `for foo in bar:` and then use methods like `index`, `find`, `remove`, etc. that have to search for the item that you already have. Just use `for index, foo in enumerate(bar):`, and then you already have the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that it only runs through the list once because… you wrote a `for` loop that explicitly runs through the list once, and no other loops.

If you want it to run through the list repeatedly, put another loop around it.

For example, since you're removing values from the original list each time through the loop, you could just keep going until you've remove them all, by adding `while List:` as an outer loop:

```
while List:
    for item in List:
        if item < (Min):
            Min = item
            nList.append(Min)
            List.remove(Min)
```

This will not actually work as-is, but that's because of other flaws in your original logic, not anything new to the `while` loop.

The first obvious problems are:

1. You're removing elements from `List` as you iterate over it. This is illegal and technically anything could happen, but what actually will happen is that your iteration will skip over some of the elements.
2. You start `Min` with `List[0]`, despite the fact that this is generally not the minimum. This means at least your first pass will add elements in the wrong order.
3. Eventually you will reach a point where `item >= Min` for every item left in `List`. What happens then? You never move anything over, and just loop forever doing nothing.

Comment: I cannot find those problems by my own thx anyway. suggestions?

Comment: @user1813564: You may want to try using a debugger or a visualizer (like [this one](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#)) to step through your code step by step as it runs over a small list. Also take a look at simple implementations of simple sorting algorithms like heap sort (what you seem to be going for) and insertion sort (effectively the exactly opposite approach) and see how they differ from yours.

Comment: See [this visualization](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=List+%3D+%5B3,+2,+1,+0,+1,+2,+3%5D%0AMin,+nList+%3D+List%5B0%5D,+%5B%5D%0A%0Afor+item+in+List%3A%0A++++if+item+%3C+(Min)%3A%0A++++++++Min+%3D+item%0A++++++++nList.append(Min)%0A++++++++List.remove(Min)&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=19) to see how your code deals with `[3,2,1,0,1,2,3]`, which demonstrates all 3 problems. After moving the `2`, the `1` is skipped. Then, `0` is added after `2` rather than before. After `0`, nothing else gets added.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing (apart from logic errors) is still sorting - it's known as [heap sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_sort), and it takes `O(n log n)` time.

If you don't keep the list as a heap, your finding the minimum will be `O(n)` instead of `O(log n)`, and your sort will run asymptotically as badly as bubble sort - `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to python so may have some unclear expression. I mean bot using built in function sort.But really learned from your comment!

Comment: @user1813564: I think the only thing that was unclear in your question was punctuation. "Sorting without 'sort'" sounds like you're making some clever point; "Sorting without `sort`" (or, even better, "Sorting without `sort()`") makes it clear that you're talking about not using the `sort` method.